# Two-day Music chart predictions and the serial correlation effect on the prediction

Tags: r, regression, predictive-models, linear-model, weighted-regression

I have about 64000 music Charts ranked by their usage frequency.
I want to have a future two-day prediction frequency and eventually its rank for each music chart using its past 21 days usage frequencies but  the frequencies are obviously correlated but because of scale, I dont want to use ARIMA related models. I am not sure what would be the effect of correlated residuals on my predictions.
Constraints:
1-Even though  the frequencies are correlated (time series data), I don't want to use ARIMA related models as for a production scale, they aren't stable and break a lot (Matrix singularities,..)

2- Because of the scale, it is very much preferable to just use the 21 data points for each record, independent of other records (no Mixed effect model)

3- The model must outperform the current method ( Using today's record rank as the predicted rank for two days later (base model). The base model for the top rank records is fairly good and hard to beat as the daily ranks don't fluctuate much.

This is what I have been doing.

1- Use this model: freq = b0 + b1 Day(-2) i.e. I use days 1:21 to predict the frequencies of  days 3:23 (day1 for freq on day3,...).  A weighted least square approach
lm(freq ~ poly(day,2),data=df,weights=wgh) is used to counter the non-constant variance.

2- Since this was not good enough, I used a weighted average of predicted frequency and the base frequency. For example  if  ( 1198,1234) are the predicted frequencies of day 23 and the actual frequency on day 21 (two days earlier(the base frequency)) respectively.
My final predicted freq for day 23 will be
** w freq_pred[23] + (1-w) freq[21] =  w * 1198 + (1-w) 1234** for some w.

That is the only way I can beat the base prediction for top records.
How can I improve my model? How will the unaccounted serial correlation will affect my results?
Are there other suggestions? Is there a big problem with this approach?